# Written date formats in US English: how jarring is it to use the UK format?

Tags: dates, localization

In general, there is a difference between the common spoken ordering of dates between US and UK usage. So in the UK, we would tend to say:

> "the 14th of December, 2005"

while in the US, people would tend to say:

> "December 14th, 2005"

The US ordering is possible in spoken usage (usually with "the", so "December the 14th, 2005"), but probably not the most common in spoken usage, and definitely not in written usage. In written UK usage-- at least in a modern written style-- one would tend to write: "14 December 2005".

Now my question: **how *jarring* does it look to a native US speaker to *write* dates using the UK format**, i.e. "14 December 2005"? Visually, I quite like the UK style because it keeps the two numbers separated, but the document I'm writing is for a US audience.

Comment: Seeing "14 December 2005" is perfectly clear to me.  What throws off us Americans is when we see the more abbreviated version, 14-12-2005.  Of course, that one wouldn't be bad but if the date were December 10th . . . 10-12-2005 could be misunderstood as October 12th.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Never use little-endian dates: write that 2005-12-14 or whatnot. ISO says so.

Comment: @tchrist - Not sure which planet you're living on, but around here people use little-endian dates ALL THE TIME.  I agree that it's a horrible practice and should be stamped out, but if you receive information from other people you generally can't just reject it as ambiguous!  I work with medical software/equipment in Los Angeles; much of the DICOM standards work was done in Europe, and so many date fields are extremely confusing. Also, non-technical people often find big-endian dates confusing.  It's horrible.

Comment: @tchrist - that was my example for the OP.  Does it cause a problem?  I'm confused.

Comment: I don't know how this correlates with *spoken* usage. Comparing US/UK corpuses in Google Books for [25th of December vs. December 25th](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=25th+of+December%2CDecember+25th&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that currently there's no significant difference, but over the first half of the 20th century, Brits were actually *more* likely to write the "American" form than Americans themselves.

Comment: "14 December 2005" would strike me as non-standard but perfectly understandable. "14-12-2005" or similar would be quite jarring. Why don't you just write the date in a format that's appropriate to your audience? It seems like the easiest solution is just to use the American format, whatever you determine that to be. To me, "December 14, 2005", or "December the 14th, 2005", or "12-14-2005" would fit the bill.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No-one uses "of" in dates like that. How about [a more realistic ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=25+December%2CDecember+25&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I used the "th" forms because OP did in his first two examples. If you exclude the ordinals you're getting further away from what I'd expect to be a reflection of *spoken* usage until relatively recently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but Ngrams document **written** English. As it's likely that "25 December" would be **said** as "25th of December", you need to look for how it is **written**.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I only wrote the second sentence in an (obviously futile) attempt to justify OP having used ordinals in the first place. I stand by *I used the "th" forms because OP did in his first two examples* - but if you've got any problem with the rest, take it up with Neil! :)

Comment: When I write for an international audience, I format my dates using Y-M-d: 2001-01-10.

Comment: Doesn't the US military use the "14 December 2005" (but not 14/12/2005) format? I think that was normal back in the 1960s when I was on active duty in the US Navy. But I may be misremembering. I prefer "14 December 2005" to "December 14th, 2005" and "December 14, 2005".

Comment: If you use numeric month, you can't even imagine the amount of ridicule and outrage Europeans express at the American middle-endian dates. Either pick Y-M-D of D-M-Y. M-D-Y is plain stupid.

Comment: @BillFranke: The U.S. military _does_ use that format, although most of the time the month is abbreviated by using the first three letters, and only the last two digits of the year are used (e.g., 14 Dec 05). That said, the four-digit year is seen more frequently since Y2K.

Comment: @BillFranke- Yes, they still do.  14-Dec-2005, or 14 December 2005 are perfectly normal date representations.

Comment: @Neil: I don't think it's jarring at all; in fact (I've mentioned this on ELU before), I've never noticed much correlation between how dates are written and how they are spoken. Put another way, I don't necessarily pronounce my dates the same way I write them.

Comment: @J.R.: More proof that the spoken and written languages are different animals. Whether they should or shouldn't be is irrelevant: they are, de facto.

Comment: @SF.: "American middle-endian dates"? We don't use middle-endian dates for numerical dates. It'd be 12/14/2005 for 14 Dec 05. Outrage is a choice (like "taking offense") & a poor way to deal with problems, but it is a marker of self-righteousness, init?

Comment: @BillFranke: 12/14/2005 - the smallest unit - day (14) - appears in the middle. That's called middle-endian. And you certainly can express outrage when you're given `12` `11` `08` as an example date in a sample of a form you're expected to fill in, and you're expected to guess the format and the right one is middle-endian.

Comment: @SF.: Oh, I guess I got the definition of "middle-endian" wrong. Sorry about that. Well, some Americans also express their outrage when they have to guess what the hell Europeans mean by their date format. Outrage is stupidity in this case. The only solution is to standardize things, just the way most of the world has done with distance measures (except the USA and the UK, of course, and there may be others), & by driving on the right side of the road instead of the left (save Japan, the UK, & others, of course). Here in Taiwan, the trains ride on the left side & the cars on the right. Stupid.

Comment: But understandable since Japan used to own Taiwan. So it's all politics, & politics (personal, office, religious, & national) is the source of most outrage. What's the point of outrage? It only hastens apoplexy & stroke. The best way to react to politics is to shake your head in knowing dismay. The other way is to exterminate all dissidents. That's been tried &, as we saw in Algeria last weekend, is still being tried. So it all comes down to the individual language user, the writer who stupidly writes 9/10/11 without telling the reader what it means. "Read my mind" it says. Outrageous! :-)

Comment: @Bill: I was hoping the "outrage" remark was said tongue-in-cheek. _Incredulity_, perhaps – but _outrage_? I hope not. I wouldn't want to see anyone get apoplectic over a date format. That would make a heck of an epitaph, though, wouldn't it? _He died after getting a check from an American, trying to figure out if it had been written on May 6th, or June 5th_. At least the American would get to keep his money.

Comment: @J.R.: I'm certainly being tongue-in-cheek. Outrage is a bit much to express over a date format. But I think SF.'s a bit more serious: he's the outraged European and repeated the word a few times. He knows what it means.

Comment: A few years' in international correspondence chess left me dissatisfied with the usual USA MDY numeric version, but I wanted to be language-neutral in dating (who knows if standard English month abbreviations mean anything to a Bulgarian opponent) and pre-PC I didn't know the ISO style, which is what I would use now. So I borrowed from Churchill (and probably many others) and used Roman numerals for the month in the middle. This would alert Americans how to read 6.VIII.75 correctly.

Comment: I agree with other comments that using numerals (1/12/13) could be misinterpreted, while spelling out the month would be quite clear. I also wanted to note, however, that using the UK format will likely indicate to your readers that you're not from the US. I don't know if that's a concern for you, but something I'd consider.

Comment: @BillFranke: Maybe "Outraged" is too strong a word, but "ired" will be the light side of spectrum of feelings this elicits. A person failing to cash a cheque with due date written as 05/06/2013, will certainly be outraged if the cashier says it's expired and was valid only until 05-06-2013.

Comment: @sf.: "Ired" is _le mot juste_. I, too, get _ired_ when I see ambiguous date formats. But, true to my working class roots, I think "pissed off". :-)

Comment: In this situation, I find the use the of the word jarring jarring.

Comment: To the title question, yes, the date/month name/year written form is jarring to most Americans. Understandable and unambiguous but out of the ordinary. Jarring is just the right word to explain the feeling on seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

The full form isn't jarring between the two. It isn't even entirely unheard of for people to use the "other" convention from that most common in their country.

Numerical dates though are another matter. It is completely impossible to know when "2/5/2013" or "02/05/2012" is referring to, without knowledge of which convention is used.

If you really need to use the numerical form, then there are three options:

1. Use the standard which is 2013-01-23 for today in Britain (BS EN 28601), America (ANSI X3.30), Ireland (IS/EN 28601) and indeed every country in the world except Norway and North Korea. And I think Norway may have adopted it recently. Downside: While it's a standard, that only really applies to technical contexts, and many people aren't familiar with it. Upside: Unambiguous, and those who aren't familiar with it can still understand it.
2. Use the convention (23/01/2013 or 23/1/2013 for Britain, 01/23/2013 or 1/23/2013 for the US) and indicate somewhere that the convention is used. Upside: What people are used to, if the reader is of the target demographic. Downside: That indication will be redundant for most, and might be missed by the rest.
3. Re-think your assumption that you really need the numerical form.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by document. I'm from Minnesota, and in a work of non-fiction seeing “14 December 2005” would lead to me assume the author is British, similar to seeing a British spelling like “colour.”  In a work of fiction, it would lead me to think the character or narrator is British.

But there is considerable variation in how dates are written in the US. US passports list expiration dates in the form “14 Dec 2005” (I assume to match the rest of the world) and receipts are all over the place. For example I've seen “Dec 14'05” on a McDonalds receipt. About the only thing you can't do in the US is write “2/1” intending it to mean the second of January.

So is it jarring? Yes, but no more so than a mixture of US and UK spelling.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear there's scope for confusion when using digits, but that's completely irrelevant to this question about spelled-out dates. Here's a compilation of five comments from Americans.

Kristina Lopez, Illinois:

> Seeing "14 December 2005" is perfectly clear to me.

J.R., United States:

> I don't think it's jarring at all; in fact (I've mentioned this on ELU before), I've never noticed much correlation between how dates are written and how they are spoken. Put another way, I don't necessarily pronounce my dates the same way I write them.

Mitch, United States:

> To the title question, yes, the date/month name/year written form is jarring to most Americans. Understandable and unambiguous but out of the ordinary. Jarring is just the right word to explain the feeling on seeing it.

Bill Franke:

> I prefer "14 December 2005" to "December 14th, 2005" and "December 14, 2005".

Patrick87:

> "14 December 2005" would strike me as non-standard but perfectly understandable.