# “25th De­cem­ber” vs “25 De­cem­ber”: Should I use or­di­nals or car­di­nals for the day of the month?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, speech, dates, ordinal-numbers

In one of the IELTS lis­ten­ing tests, there is a fill-out-the-blank ques­tion read­ing:

> The mu­seum is not open on  ___.

My an­swer was “25th De­cem­ber”. How­ever, the of­fi­cial an­swer is “25 De­cem­ber”.
Is my an­swer also cor­rect? Why did they not in­clude *th* there in their an­swer?

On the other hand, in an­other such ques­tion like:

> Date: ___.

Here now the of­fi­cial for­mat is like “10th De­cem­ber” **with** a *th*. Why did they now include the *th* in this answer but omitted it in the earlier answer?

Which date for­mat should I use in what cir­cum­stances, and why?

How is it to be pro­nounced in words?

Comment: You won't lose a point for not writing "th" especially if the speaker in the listening track actually *says* 25th (twenty-fifth) Does he/she?

Comment: 22th is wrong, it's 22**nd**

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m trying to work out whether the writer fully realizes that that succinct written notation “always” needs extra words to make it sound right to the ear. I bet they don’t know that no matter whether you write *“Christmas falls on 25 December”* with a cardinal number or you write *“Christmas falls on 25**th** December”* with an explicitly ordinal number, that one not only reads/speaks it with an ordinal, but read aloud surrounds that spoken ordinal with the little words *the* and *of*, thus yielding “Christmas falls on ***“the** twenty-fifth **of** December”* in the spoken form.

Comment: As­sorted pos­si­ble du­pli­cates and tan­gen­tially re­lated ques­tions:
[What is the best for­mat to use when writ­ing out dates?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/420/2085),
[Date for­mat in UK vs US](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68844/2085),
[How to write out dates cor­rectly](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68573/2085),
[Writ­ten date for­mats in US English: how jar­ring is it to use the UK for­mat?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/100971/2085),
[Date for­mats for Amer­i­cans](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/63801/2085).

Answer (score -3):

I'm an IELTS tutor. IELTS **generally** follows *BrE* where the date is mentioned first, then the month, and lastly the year. In addition, IELTS is very strict in Listening and Reading section where you are not supposed to add even a preposition or article if it's not asked or required.

Well, coming to your question, you are ***writing*** the answer. The confusion occurs in dates because you write and speak it differently!

In writing, *generally*, we use a cardinal number. That said, it is -

> 25 December

But when someone *asks* you *'What date is it?'*, you may answer with an ordinal number:

> 25th December

---

Additional reading: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/writing-dates

Comment: Isn't December 25th also appropriate?

Comment: That is appropriate, but then, it makes it NAmE @suse

Comment: Read: *the* twenty-fifth *of* December.

Comment: Hi Maulik V, Thanks for your answer. I found some IELTS listening answer written as 13th February (C4-T1-S1), but the question is like Date: ___.  Is it relating to the position?   I mean if there is only one blank without in sentence, we should answer in Ordinal numbers.

Comment: Hey, as far as **writing dates** in IELTS are concerned, don't worry! Almost all forms are okay, but to be safe, write a number and then a month [check here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/DatesAndNumbersInEnglish/mxzzh/post.htm)

Comment: @user332314 yes, why take a risk of writing something superscript? So, the safest is without any 'st/nd/th'